# How to invest in El Salvador bonds via fidelity

Tags: 401k, bonds, foreign-exchange

El Salvador bonds have gone down lately and I would like to invest in them. I use Fidelity to manage my 401k investment fund, but I can't find any symbol to invest in related to El Salvador bonds.

Is there a fund of some sort that I can purchase that primarily deals with El Salvador bonds? I am based out of the USA.

Comment: Do you know _why_ they've gone down in value? What makes you think they will come back up?

Comment: https://www.etftrends.com/innovative-etfs-channel/get-el-salvador-exposure-with-this-etf-after-country-legalizes-bitcoin/

Comment: The imf downgraded their credit rating hitting their govt bonds, but I think the imf is wrong and I want to bet against them

Comment: Thanks @DStanley for the link regarding PCY. I wish there was a fund that was more focused on El Salvador rather than being a general emerging markets one.

Answer (score 1):

Most 401(k) programs have a very limited list of investments they allow. Many times it is a handful of stock funds (S&P 500, small cap...), some bond funds, a few international choices, and the rest are geared to the estimated retirement date of the employee.

There as some companies that do allow the participants to access a broader set of investments via the investment company they work with. It is even possible that every possible investment is available.

If your 401(k) program doesn't allow you to pick from this broader set of investments, then you will have to invest in those El Salvador bonds via an IRA or a taxable account.

Comment: It's really an account where I can invest in any stocks and mutual funds like a fidelity IRA. I just don't know what to lookup to invest in symbol wise.